# Node.js ReadStream stuck on Electron when piping to Hash

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron

I am creating this application with [vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/) and [vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder](https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder) and I'm having this weird problem, specific to electron, where once the application starts the first `ReadStream` created will not pipe its contents to the given stream.

Now, refreshing the application through `CTRL + F5` will make the streams work again, and from there on there won't be any problems anymore.

My current code is something similar to and is called on the Render Thread once the application starts:

```js
public async run() {
  await this.scanFolder("/some/path/to/a/folder");
}

private async scanFolder(path: string){
  const entries = readdirSync(path, { withFileTypes: true });

  for (const entry of entries){
    if (!entry.isDirectory()){
      const md5 = await calculateMD5(path + "/" + entry.name);
    }
  }
}

public static async calculateFileMD5(path: string) {
  const md5 = createHash("md5");
  md5.setEncoding("hex");

  console.log("Creating promise");
  const promise = new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
    const fileStream = createReadStream(path, {
      autoClose: true,
      emitClose: true
    });

    fileStream.on("open", () => console.log("STREAM OPEN"));
    fileStream.on("ready", () => console.log("STREAM READY"));
    fileStream.on("close", () => {
      console.log("Stream closed");
      resolve(md5.read());
    });

    fileStream.on("data", data => {
      console.log(data);
    });

    fileStream.on("end", () => {
      console.log("Stream ENDED");
      resolve(md5.read());
    });

    fileStream.on("error", error => {
      console.error(error);
      reject(error);
    });

    console.log("Piping to MD5");
    fileStream.pipe(md5, { end: true });
    fileStream.resume();
    console.log("Is paused?: " + fileStream.isPaused());
  });
  console.log("Returning promise");
  return promise;
}
```

Starting up the application with `npm run electron:serve` and calling the `run` function will output this:

```
Creating promise
Piping to MD5
Is paused?: false
Returning promise
STREAM OPEN
STREAM READY
```

Now, if the application is reloaded through `CRTL + F5` the stream properly pipes its contents to the Hash.

Is there anything I can do to make it not require a refresh once the application starts for the streams to work properly?